# View house data in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, zillow

I have just read the details of a house address using the Zillow API in my Jupyter Notebook. I wanted to know if there is a way of displaying the data in a dataframe.

```
with open("./bin/config/zillow_key.conf", 'r') as f:
    key = f.readline().replace("\n", "")
address = "379 Melrose Ave, San Francisco, CA"
postal_code = "94127"

data = api.GetSearchResults(key, address, postal_code)
```

Comment: Can you share an example for the result returned from the function `GetSearchResults`?

Comment: It doesn't display anything. It just runs successfully.